# Change the frame width in Emacs, Interactively

Tags: emacs

I know you can change the frame size in the .emacs file with `set-frame-width` or `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(width . 80))` but how can I change the width after Emacs has started up (aside from dragging the edge of the frame)?

Comment: FWIW, the answers below are all good, but it's really the job of your
window manager to manage windows.  If you don't currently use one that
is easily-controllable from the keyboard, I recommend you try Xmonad.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, go to the `*scratch*` buffer and use `set-frame-width`.

```
(set-frame-width (selected-frame) 100)  ;; ^J to execute.
```

`set-frame-width` isn't interactive, so you can't run it with `M-x` but you could trivially write a set-frame-width-interactive, something like

```
(defun set-frame-width-interactive (arg)
   (interactive "p")
   (set-frame-width (selected-frame) arg))
```

Now `C-u 8 0 M-x set-frame-width-interactive` will set the width to 80.

Is this what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Charlie Martin's suggestions, you can do

```
M-: (set-frame-width (selected-frame) N)
```

Answer (score 6):

This library has a bunch of interactive commands for your use:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/frame-cmds.el

Here are a few relevant ones:

```
enlarge-frame
enlarge-frame-horizontally
hide-frame
mouse-show-hide-mark-unmark
move-frame-down
move-frame-left
move-frame-right
move-frame-up
show-a-frame-on
show-frame
shrink-frame
shrink-frame-horizontally
tile-frames
```

Comment: Both frame-cmds and frame-fns (its dependency) are available as packages from [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/).

Answer (score 3):

To toggle between 2 frame sizes easily you could define something like that (e.g., add it to your ".emacs" file) (adapt the sizes to your screen and fonts)

```
     (defvar myfullscreen '()
       "non-nil if current frame is in fullscreen mode. See myfullscreen-on, myfullscreen-off, myfullscreen-toggle")

     (defun myfullscreen-on ()
       "Sets fullscreen on (based on ???display??? with font ???)"
       (interactive)
       (set-frame-width (selected-frame) 177); adapt size
       (set-frame-height (selected-frame) 58); adapt size
       (setq myfullscreen t)
       )

     (defun myfullscreen-off ()
       "Sets fullscreen off (based on ???display??? with font ???)"  
       (interactive)
       (set-frame-width (selected-frame) 110); adapt size
       (set-frame-height (selected-frame) 58); adapt size
       (setq myfullscreen nil)
       )

     (defun myfullscreen-toggle ()
       "Toggles fullscreen on/off (based on ???Display??? with font ???)"    
       (interactive)
       (if (eq myfullscreen 'nil)
           (myfullscreen-on)
                                    ;else
         (myfullscreen-off)
         )
       )
```

Then, you can use

M-x myfullscreen-on

M-x myfullscreen-off

M-x myfullscreen-toggle

and/or bind them to your favorite key bindings